# Heat generated in a rod due to forces on its ends

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, elasticity

Given is a uniform rod of length $l$,cross-sectional area $A$ , Young's modulus $\gamma$. Forces F and 2F are applied at it's ends.

To find the heat generated in it, I first went in the frame of the rod , generating a pseudo force F at it's COM .
[image: pseudo force F at center]

(Sorry for the crude image)

As seen in the lower image I took the rods in two sections as shown,as they are easier to deal with .
Then as there is no kinetic energy in its own frame, $W_force-U$=$H$

For $W_F$ F being constant ,and
$F/A$=2$Y$($\Delta l$/$l$)
Where $\Delta l$is the final extension.

By substituting appropriate values for each of the two half rods ($l/2$ in length)

$W_force$ = $5F^2 l /2AY$. (Simply by force ×displacememt,the larger force rod contributes four times the smaller one.).

As for U , it would be half of W because of restoring force depending on x (change in length each instant) and hence the integral for work would give a factor of 1/2.
From this the Heat H is supposed to be$5F^2 l /4AY$

Which happens to be the wrong answer. So my question is wether or not is correct to break the forces as I had above into two rods , And if not then why not and what could be the correct case.
Thank you

Comment: Please give the exact problem statement, including any diagrams.

Comment: A rod of length $l$ ,cross sectional area A and Young's modulus $Y$ is subjected to two forces $F$ and $2F$ at its two ends. The heat generated in the rod is found to be $(10a+b)F^2 l / 12AY $ .  Find $a+b$.    a,b are positive integers.

Comment: I guess you're looking for something like [this](http://fiitjeefaridabad.weebly.com/uploads/8/6/6/9/8669642/aits-1718-ft-vii-paper-1___solutions.pdf) (page 20). I can't comment on the solution, which appears indecipherable to me. Notes like "k will remains zero finally from COM frame" is far from understandable, grammatical English.